# how to solve CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) no credential error?

Tags: reactjs, cors, vite, mern

i am getting cors no allow credentials error/ cors error xhr .

```
const app = express();
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  methods: "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true,
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
}));
app.options('*', cors());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opn5M.png)

its connecting to database (as collection is created but those are empty)

register login not working due to cors error.

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(process.env.CLIENT_URL)`?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://localhost:4040/profile’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { stack: "AxiosError@http://127.0.0.1:4040/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=228e7607:369:18\nhandleError@http://127.0.0.1:4040/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=228e7607:1434:14\n", message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }

Comment: access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4040/profile' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4040' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. ( in chrome)

Comment: try accessing http://localhost:4040 from your browser

Comment: @user21731222 Edit your question and add the relevant information there rather than in the comment section.

Comment: i fixed it but not sure if its ready for deployment